# why there is not output from spawned process show using escript

Tags: erlang

please could you enlighten me why following code is not using stdout if run using **escript**?

```
main(_) ->                                                                                                 
    spawn(fun() -> io:fwrite("blah") end).
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fwrite` still writes to stdout when running in an escript, the problem here is that your program terminates before the spawned process has had a chance to run!

The escript terminates as soon as the `main` function terminates, depending on how the virtual machine scheduled your spawned process you may or may not get the `fwrite` executed.

A simple workaround for your example is to add some synchronization:

```
main(_) ->
  MainPid=self(),
  spawn(fun() -> io:fwrite("blah"), MainPid ! done end),
  receive
    done -> 
      ok
  end.
```

This makes the main process wait with termination until the spawned process has sent a message.

Comment: Thanks! How would you handle such sync in some real case - let's say to wait for main to finish all processes till die - named processes?

Comment: You would need a similar sync. e.g. collect the id:s of the processes you should wait for, loop over the list `receive`ing a message from each process. When the list is empty all the processes have finished.